# Ant: All Directory under Current Directory

Tags: ant, directory, ant-contrib

I am trying to figure out all the directory under my current directory. Current directory may contain files and directories.

In this scenario, I am looking for existing task which can provide me all the sub-directories under current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

    <target name="run">
        <dirset id="dirs" dir="${basedir}/.."/>

        <pathconvert targetos="unix" property="path.unix" refid="dirs"/>

        <echo message="${path.unix}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the -path option and the -sbudirectory option, like this:

```
find . -type d -path "./dir1/*.1" -"subdirectory*name" -o -print
```